# I cannot resolve this : " ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create') "

Tags: javascript, typescript, nestjs

```
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { CustomRepository } from 'src/typeorm/typeorm-ex.decorator';
import { User } from './user.entity';

@CustomRepository(User)
export class UserRepository extends Repository<User> {
  async createUser(userData: Partial<User>): Promise<User> {
    const user = this.create?.(userData);
    return await this.save?.(user);
  }
}
```

This is my user.repository.ts file.
Since EntityRepository was deprecated, I made a custom repository.
I made some methods about this, and when tried to use it, this error appeared.

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'create')
```

I did some researches about the same error, but none of them were quite helpful.
How can I fix this?

I tried putting

```
    if (this.create === undefined) {
      return;
    }
```

right under the declaration of createUser method, and it didn't work.

I also tried doing this:

```
const user = this.create?.(userData);
    return await this.save?.(user);
```

but it didn't work either.

Comment: Well, `this` object doesn't have a `create` property, so check your class `Repository<User>`.

Comment: you can try declare your `create` property at the top of `Repository<User>` class (outside the constructor) or `CustomRepository` mark, I guess

Comment: with mark I mean decorator

Comment: If you are using version 0.3.0 of TypeORM or greater, the `@CustomRepository()` approach has been deprecated. You should either `@InjectRepository(User)` into your `UserRepository` and use `this.repo.create()` or you should follow TypeORM's new custom repository appraoch